# Calculate limit $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{2^{4n+1} \ln(2n^3+1)+n^5\cdot 10^n}{15^n+4^{2n-1} \ln (5n)}$ with approximations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{2^{\left(4n+1\right)} \ln\left(2n^3+1\right)+n^5\cdot 10^n}{15^n+4^{\left(2n-1\right)} \ln\left(5n\right)}\right)$$

I tried like that:
$$\approx\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{2^{\left(4x+1\right)}}{4^{\left(2x-1\right)}}\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{16^x2}{\frac{16^x}{4}}\right)=8$$

Wolfram says that should come 24, i probably deleted also useful parts, can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading term in the numerator is
$$
2^{4n+1} \ln (2n^3+1) = 2^{4n+1} \cdot 3 \ln n \cdot (1+o(1))
$$
The leading term in the denominator is
$$
4^{2n-1} \ln (5n) = 2^{4n-2} \cdot \ln n \cdot (1+o(1))
$$

You missed the factor $3$ emerging from the logarithms. You could not neglect these logarithms: they are multiplicative factors.

Answer (score 0):

Your title appears to be very misleading. We don't calculate limits via approximations, but by using various theorems related to evaluation of limits. Here we need to use the following results $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log n} = 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty}n^{k}x^{n}$$ where $|x| < 1, k > 0$.

We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{4n + 1} \log(2n^{3} + 1)+n^{5}\cdot 10^{n}}{15^{n} + 4^{2n - 1} \log(5n)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2\log(2n^{3} + 1) + n^{5}\cdot (10/16)^{n}}{(15/16)^{n} + 4^{-1} \log(5n)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{8\log(2n^{3} + 1) + 4n^{5}\cdot (10/16)^{n}}{4(15/16)^{n} + \log(5n)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{8\cdot\dfrac{\log(2n^{3} + 1)}{\log(5n)} + 4\cdot\dfrac{n^{5}\cdot (10/16)^{n}}{\log(5n)}}{4\cdot\dfrac{(15/16)^{n}}{\log(5n)} + 1}\notag\\
&= 8\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(2n^{3} + 1)}{\log(5n)}\notag\\
&= 8\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log 2 + 3\log n + \log(1 + 1/2n^{3})}{\log 5 + \log n}\notag\\
&= 8\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{\log 2}{\log n} + 3 + \dfrac{\log(1 + 1/2n^{3})}{\log n}}{\dfrac{\log 5}{\log n} + 1}\notag\\
&= 8\cdot\frac{0 + 3 + 0}{0 + 1}\notag\\
&= 24\notag
\end{align}